# How can I make a rails blog display a random post at homepage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What I want is that each time someone lands on my blog, they will see one random post on the homepage. What's the best way to define a method in the controller that I can call into the views for this to happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a Post model and a record in the DB for each post, do something like:

```
def index
  @post = Post.offset(rand(Post.count)).first
end
```

...then in your view, just display the content of `@post`.

Comment: Beat me to it. More elegant than what I was typing up, too. :)

Comment: Hey Thanks!, but for some reason nothing is displaying on my views.

Comment: Very nicely put together

Comment: @alex - Your code to fetch random post will fire two queries i.e one to count post and the other to select the post. I would recommend to go with Mike's answer.

Comment: @Addicted, both will work, but I prefer this solution. For one thing, it is portable. Second, it is performant even when run on large tables. A good reference here is page 183 of PragProg's *SQL Antipatterns* -- they regard the query given in the other solution as an "antipattern".

Comment: @user3546559, then you'll have to use your debugging skills to find out what is happening. I'm just showing you how to select a random post from your database. Is the table empty? Is there some bug in your view? Try looking at the HTML which you are generating, using your browser's "View Source", or a tool like `wget`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid multiple queries, you can use your DBMS's `RANDOM` (`RAND` in MySQL) function to order the records, and then `LIMIT 1`. For example with MySQL:

```
@post = Post.order("rand()").limit(1)
```

Comment: do I just put <%= @post %> in the view?